# Query returns false information on column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

If you run this:

```
SELECT  o.orderid,suppliername,p.productname
FROM Suppliers s
JOIN Orders o
ON o.shipperid = s.supplierid
JOIN OrderDetails od
ON od.orderid = o.orderid
JOIN Products p 
ON p.productid = od.productid
```

On https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_count

You get resuls where for each order-id, there is a set of rows with productnames and suppliernames. 
Now, the funny thing is that for each Order as a whole (say a set of two rows for order 10300)
there is always the SAME suppliername.

But this isnt true. When you look up the table "products" you will find that for example for the products with ID 66 and 68, which are the products contained in order 10300, there are two different supplier IDs registered. 2 and 8. 
And these resolve to two different suppliernames on the supplieres table.

Why is that? This is a fairly simple query in my opinion, I didnt expect to run into any issues with it. But here, the data presented to me in the tables and the data returned by the query clearly diverge. 
Am I missing something or is their site/DB just broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the way you are joining to the Suppliers table. Instead of joining the Suppliers table to the Orders table, it seems like you want to join the Products to the Suppliers tables to get the suppliers for those products. Such a query would look like:

```
SELECT  o.orderid, s.suppliername, p.productname
FROM Orders o
    JOIN OrderDetails od ON od.orderid = o.orderid
    JOIN Products p ON p.productid = od.productid
    JOIN Suppliers s ON s.supplierid = p.supplierid
```

Comment: Wow, big thanks! I didnt know that the order/arrangement of the JOINS can have such an impact! You really helped me out there, never wouldve guessed that this causes the problem xD

Comment: its not the orders of the joins that caused your issue but the criteria for the joins. You had "o.shipperid = s.supplierid" causing the problem when "s.supplierid = p.supplierid" is what you intended. if you have the table first or fourth, it makes no difference.